# How to get contents of arraylist from first activity in second activity

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

All Task.java

```
public class AllTask extends AppCompatActivity{


    ArrayList<Company> companyList;
    Bundle extras;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task_list);


        companyList=new ArrayList<>();
        companyList.add(new Company("Kony Labs","10:30","Good"));
        companyList.add(new Company("Delloite","12:30","Very Good"));
        companyList.add(new Company("Accenture","14:30","Average"));
        companyList.add(new Company("Microsoft","16:30","Very Good"));
        companyList.add(new Company("TCS","18:30","Good"));


    }
}
```

AllReports.java

```
public class AllReports extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Company> report_companyList;
    Bundle extras;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_reports);


        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Reports");

        AllTask all_tasks=new AllTask();
        report_companyList=new ArrayList<>(all_tasks.companyList);



        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.report_list);

        MyAdapterResults myAdapter=new MyAdapterResults(this,R.layout.list_view_row_item,report_companyList);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

I want to show data in ArrayList in first activity in `ListView` from the second activity but when I am trying to get data from first activity in second it is giving `NullPointerException` that ArrayList is empty. How to get the contents of ArrayList in the second activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `companyList` static

```
static ArrayList<Company> companyList;
```

and call it like this :

```
AllTask.companyList
```

This approach is not recommended. You should instead implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` in your `Company` class and pass the data like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("data", companyList);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and read it from second activity like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();
List<Company> data= (List<Company>)bundle.getSerializable("data");
```

Comment: Although this solution works, if the dataset gets too large, serializable is going to be really slow compared to a `Parcelable` solution.

Comment: in the edit it's added `Parcelable` for real it's better than any other solution but  i didn't have a good practice with it also "Serializable" it's simple for someone new at android development

Comment: I agree, and I've upvoted the answer. I just think it's good for the new devs to know that there's also other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, make your Company object as Serializable

```
public class Company implements Serializable {
  //Your code
}
```

From AllTask Activity you should open AllReports like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AllReports.class);

intent.putExtra("companyList", companyList);

startActivity(intent);
```

You can get in AllReports, like this,

```
ArrayList<Company> companyList = (ArrayList<Company>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("companyList");
```

Comment: using Serializable on Android is considered bad practice, use Parcelable instead

Answer (score 0):

You should send it through intent.

first of all make your Company bean implements Serializable

then in your firstActivity do this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("array",companyList);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And then in your SecondActitvity in your onCreate do it like this:

```
 ArrayList<Company> companyList = (ArrayList<Company>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Parcelable array to your activity. It is more efficient than Serializable, for Android at least. But your company should implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for that.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

        ArrayList<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();
        //fill companies

        i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("EXTRA", companies);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayList<Company> companies = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("EXTRA");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer with a non-native solution.

You could also use Green Robot's [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to achieve what you want, without having to work with `Serializable` or the boilerplate of `Parcelable`. With the advantage of being much faster than both when you're dealing with large datasets, or many Activity calls. It also have the advantage of not having to write too much boilerplate code if your pojo/bean/class have many fields.

First, add the dependency on your `build.gradle`.

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Then, define an Event class that will be responsible to carry your data through the app. Note that this could be from one `Activity` to another. From a `Fragment` to another. A `Service` back to an `Activity`, and so on.

**MessageEvent.java**

```
public class MessageEvent { 
    public ArrayList<Company> mCompanyList;
    // Add additional fields here if needed

    public MessageEvent(ArrayList<Company> list) {
        this.mCompanyList = list;
    }
}
```

Now, you can either define a subscriber, or just post an `stickyEvent` and get it on `ActivityB`. Like the two examples below.

### Option 1: Defining subscriber

**ActivityB.java**

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ...

     @Override
     public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
     }

    @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
        EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(event);
        ArrayList<Company> list = event.mCompanyList;
        // Do whatever you want to do with the data.
    };
}
```

**ActivityA.java**

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    private void startActB(ArrayList<Company> list) {
        Intent it = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);

        EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEvent(list));

        startActivity(it);
    }
}
```

### Option 2: Getting sticky event on `ActivityB` without subscribing

**ActivityA.java**

Just do like the sample above and post the `MessageEvent` and start `ActivityB`.

**ActivityB.java**

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Company> mCompanyList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        // Other stuff you might want to do here.

        // Get the event that was posted on Activity A.
        MessageEvent event = EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(MessageEvent.class);

        // Check if it exists.
        if (event != null) {
            mCompanyList = event.mCompanyList;
            // Do whatever you want with it.
        }
        else {
            // Do something if the event wasn't posted prior to this Activity call.
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can refer to [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160624041042/http://www.stevenmarkford.com/passing-objects-between-android-activities/) to check how fast the EventBus can run compared with `Serializable` and `Parcelable`.

For more details, you can check the [project page](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/), or [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@cainwong/using-an-eventbus-in-android-pt-2-sticking-your-config-905e17864c28).

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this using Application class it allows you to use the same object using in various Activity, Fragment or Dialog.

Only one object creates and it may use in multiple times
Access from anywhere of the Application
I am adding a sample code which I have used:

```
public class Application extends Application {
ArrayList<Filepath> arrayFilePath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constant.Userdata.USER_PREF.name(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
public ArrayList<Filepath> getArrayListForImagePath() {
        String fileurl = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.Userdata.ARRAYLISTFILEPATH.name(), "");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (fileurl.isEmpty()) {
            arrayFilePath = new ArrayList<Filepath>();
        } else {
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Filepath>>() {
            }.getType();
            arrayFilePath = gson.fromJson(fileurl, type);
        }
        return arrayFilePath;
    }

    public void setArrayListForImagePath(ArrayList<Filepath> imagePath) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String jsonFilepath = gson.toJson(imagePath);

        editor.putString(Constant.Userdata.ARRAYLISTFILEPATH.name(), jsonFilepath);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void clearArrayListForImagePath() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove(Constant.Userdata.ARRAYLISTFILEPATH.name()).commit();
    }
```

**Constant Class:**

```
public class Constant {

    enum Userdata {
        USER_PREF, USER_ID, ARRAYLISTFILEPATH
    }
}
```