# passing ArrayList<E> from class to another fragment

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` in my GridView Adapter, and I need to send this list to another fragment,how can I do that? because I cannot send it via bundle.

Comment: you have to explain clearly. In which case you need it. Both fragment is alive or pass it before the fragment started?

Comment: Are you sending from one fragment to another?

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548223/how-to-get-contents-of-arraylist-from-first-activity-in-second-activity/45590882#45590882) link. This is a way to do your task.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs I want to pass it from one adapter to an alive fragment!

Comment: can you post adapter code with fragment

Comment: @ElvisChweya no, I explained that my arrayList is in my adapter and I need to send it to fragment

Comment: The adapter is in the fragment? If so, you need to add a getter for the `ArrayList`. After you `adapter.getItemList();` you can use an interface to pass that via the host activity/fragment

Comment: Post your fragment and adapter code to suggest you a solution

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs I used serializable that described in answered bellow, and it worked! thank you for your time and energy!

Comment: @AzinNilchi  your question, you told you can't use bundle so I have not suggested it. Anyway, good to hear your problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<arrayList > arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

pass the arrayList to the bundle

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("key", arrayList);
```

and in the receiving fragment

```
ArrayList<arrayList > arrayList = (ArrayList<arrayList>)getArguments().getSerializable("key");
```

Comment: you cannot just serialize a generic arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Say your arraylist is of type model class Sample.Then the model class should implement Parcelable class like this

```
public class Sample implements Parcelable {
private String name;
private int value;

protected Sample(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    value = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<Sample> CREATOR = new Creator<Sample>() {
    @Override
    public Sample createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Sample(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Sample[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Sample[size];
    }
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeInt(value);
}}
```

Then while sending data from one class to another

```
ArrayList<Sample>arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("key", arrayList);
```

Then in the other class while getting data

```
ArrayList<arrayList>arrayList=(ArrayList<Sample>)getArguments().putParcelableArrayList("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Instance class for passing data through out application

```
  public class RuntimeData {

    private Context context;
     private List<PoJo> questionHolders = new ArrayList<>();


    private RuntimeData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private static RuntimeData instance;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RuntimeData(context);
        }
    }

    public static RuntimeData getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }



    public void setQuestionHolders(List<PoJo> questionHolders) {
        this.questionHolders = questionHolders;
    }

    public List<PoJo> getQuestionHolders() {
        return questionHolders;
    }

}
```

Pojo.class

```
public class PoJo {

    private String name;

    private setName(String name) {
        this.context = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

For set value :

```
RuntimeData.getInstance().setQuestionHolders(<here your arraylist>);
```

For get value :

```
RuntimeData.getInstance().getQuestionHolders();
```